# Ec2 through AMI, DNS and SSL automation

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, ansible, cloud, build-automation

We have a project and we are working on creating bulk Ec2 t2.micro instances on demand. The automation process would be

1. Creating an instance
2. update the DNS zone with Correct public IP
3. Get Lets encrypt latest certificate.

We are using Jenkins and Ansible for this task. do you guys think if there is any better or easy approach then this.

Comment: Elastic beanstaslk would provide you with Elastic IP automatically. So this may be helpful.

Comment: Great Tip Thanks alot. any other suggestion on improvement, always welcome.  :)

Answer (score 0):

The issues of an automated creation and management of instance and a **static public IP** can be solved by means of [Elastic Beanststalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/Welcome.html) (EB).

EB also gives you a **DNS name** for free, but this is AWS DNS. If you want to use your custom domain for DNS, you can use Route53 for that as explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-beanstalk-environment.html).

**SSL certificate** depends on your EB environment. If you choose to use EB with load-balancer, then you can easly get free public SSL cert using [ACM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/index.html). If you don't want load balancer, you can install free public certificate from LetsEncrypt. But you have to manually set it up on your EB instance.